# Selenium wrong selectors leading no no output

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape this website
[Best Western Mornington Hotel](https://www.bestwestern.co.uk/hotels/best-western-mornington-hotel-london-hyde-park-83187/in-2021-06-03/out-2021-06-05/adults-1/children-0/rooms-1)

for the name of hotel rooms and the price of said room. I'm using Selenium to try and scrape this data but  I keep on getting no return after what I assume is me using the wrong selectors/XPATH. Is there any method of identifying the correct XPATH/div class/selector? I feel like I have selected the correct ones but there is no output.

```
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

seleniumurl = 'https://www.bestwestern.co.uk/hotels/best-western-mornington-hotel-london-hyde-park-83187/in-2021-06-03/out-2021-06-05/adults-1/children-0/rooms-1'



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(seleniumurl)
time.sleep(5)
working = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('room-type-block')

for work in working:
    name = work.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/h4').string
    price = work.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]').string
    print(name,price)
```

Answer (score 1):

I only work with Selenium in Java, but from I can see you're trying to get collection of WebElements and invoke toString() on them...

should be that **find_element_by_xpath** to get just one WebElement and then call **.text** instead of .string?

Answer (score 1):

Marek is right use .text instead of .string. Or use .get_attribute("innerHTML"). I also think your xpath may be wrong unless I'm looking at the wrong page. Here are some xpaths from the page you linked.

```
#This will get all the room type sections.
roomTypes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'room-type-box__content')]")

#This will get the room type titles
roomTypes.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'room-type-title')]/h3")

#Print out room type titles
for r in roomTypes:
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this selector *`div#rr_wrp div.room-type-block`* and **`.visibility_of_all_elements_located`** method for get category `div` list.

With the above selector, you can search title by this xpath: `.//h2[@class="room-type--title"]`, sub category by `.//strong[@class="trimmedTitle rt-item--title"]` and price `.//div[@class="rt-rate-right--row group"]//span[@data-bind="text: priceText"]`.

And please try the following code with [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) loop to extract parallel list:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.bestwestern.co.uk/hotels/best-western-mornington-hotel-london-hyde-park-83187/in-2021-06-03/out-2021-06-05/adults-1/children-0/rooms-1')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#rr_wrp div.room-type-block')))
for element in elements:
    for room_title in element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h2[@class="room-type--title"]'):
        print("Main Title ==>> " +room_title.text)
        for room_type, room_price in zip(element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//strong[@class="trimmedTitle rt-item--title"]'), element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="rt-rate-right--row group"]//span[@data-bind="text: priceText"]')) :
            print(room_type.text +" " +room_price.text)
            
driver.quit()
```